# How to achieve this in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am looking at Avast, Lookout for example and I am trying to understand the concept of the implementation. So it is more like asking for direction for me.

1. Persistent App icon in Notification bar.
   Am I correct to say there are function NotificationManager is able to do it?
2. Scan virus during app installation, I am not interested in virus scanning but the triggering mechanism.
   Some kind of Android service bind to the main app?
3. Main app that can be bring up in the Notification menu.
   A main app that remain trigger action to the bind services?

So what do I need to read to understand? NoticationManager, Services and ??

In short, I want to load a icon in the notification bar that can bring up my app. There is a background service that perform specific task for a set interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, `NotificationManager` and `Notification` can help you with that.
You just need to create the notification with flag `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` (to make it persistent). Even better if your service IS REALLY performing some long-running task, if so, you can start your service via Service.startForeground which needs some 'ongoing' notification for running (notification is required to notify the user that there is some work going now).

For triggering app install event, you can use `BroadcastReceiver` with filter by `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`.

Comment: Thanks kknot for point me the way, now I have direction to look at implementation.

Comment: Hi, I have implemented the notification with FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT. Is there a way to clear the notification? I try mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID) and is not working, I read somewhere FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT cannot be clear?

Comment: Another question, if I flag on FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT does that mean my app is always active? Do I still need to implement services?

Comment: flag ongoing event is not necceserry points that your app running, for achive this, you anyway need the service.

Comment: Hi kknot, so the service will still runs even my app has been stopped?

Comment: no, service just keeps your app running, even if no activity's is shown. but it still might be killed. If you use foreground service (which is started via startForeground(..)) your app will killed only in extremal memory pressure.

Comment: I wanted to trigger some activity base on timer, I think I can use AlarmManager and LocalBroadcastManager or should I use handler and service?

Comment: how often timer will fire? if often (seconds, several minutes) it would be better to use handlers, if else better to use BroadcastReceiver's. btw, not sure, localbroadcastmanager appeared only in recent versions of android.

Comment: Can AlarmManager be use for recurring events? which overwrite it's previous alarm?

Comment: So far I have completed Notification bar with FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT, I did the BOOT_COMPLETED and is all working fine. I have the broadcastreciever to launch my main app after BOOT_COMPLETED but can I not bring the app in foreground after BOOT_COMPLETED? I can think of putting something to indicate it was load from the broadcastreceiver and did a finish()? Is there proper way to do that?

Comment: I load the notification in broadcastreceiver instead of main intent that solve the issue, now left the AlarmManager thing..

Comment: yes, alarm manager can be used for recurring events(which/not overwriting previous alarm).